# Run Renjin Java-API on Wildfly 9

Tags: java, r, jboss, wildfly, renjin

i'm trying to run R Renjin Script Engine on Wildfly 9.

When i run my Java/Renjin Application, which works fine on local execution, by using it on Wildfly as EJB-Project i get the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Renjin Script Engine not found on the classpath.
```

I had already add an module (JBOSS_HOME\modules\system\layers\base\org\renjin\renjin-script-engine\main) with the jar file (renjin-script-engine-0.7.0-RC7-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and the
module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.renjin.renjin-script-engine">
<resources>
<resource-root path="renjin-script-engine-0.7.0-RC7-jar-with-dependencies.jar"/> 
</resources>
</module>
```

Do i need to add the R home-directory to JBoss java.class.path get run Renjin and how can i add that path(R_HOME) to JBoss' java classpath?

Comment: Renjin exposes a script engine.  You need to add `services="import"` to your module reference in `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`

Comment: Renjin only requires that its jar be on the classpath, no need for an extra R_HOME directory. You also might want to use a more recent version; 0.7.1578 is the most recent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. I solve it by moving the API from lib of the java EJB project to superordinate EAR project. So you do not need to create a module on your wildfly server.